# Order by in Thymeleaf

Tags: html, sql-order-by, thymeleaf

I need show this `foreach` by order `Asc`, how can I do it?

```
<tr th:each="ment : ${mentor}" th:if="${ment.jobId == job.id}">
    <td th:text="${ment.id}"></td>
    <td th:text="${ment.name}"></td>
    <td th:text="${ment.qtyMentee}"></td>
    <td th:text="${ment.jobId}"></td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This could be achieved with sort utility methods for lists, described [here](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#lists).

```
/*
 * Sort a copy of the given list. The members of the list must implement
 * comparable or you must define a comparator.
 */
${#lists.sort(list)}
${#lists.sort(list, comparator)}
```

Example

```
<tr th:each="ment : ${#lists.sort(mentor)}">
```

Comment: Ok, i try to use it, but tomcat returns "nested exception is java.lang.StackOverflowError", to order my list by qtyMentees how I do?

Comment: Check this thread: http://forum.thymeleaf.org/lists-sort-with-java-util-List-provided-by-Spring4-td4027684.html

Answer (score 0):

I had StackOverflow also, in my case I forgot to implement Comparable:

```
 Comparable<E>
```

The error was missleading, thymeleaf could recognize that compareable needs to be implemented.