# Thymeleaf - converting a set to an ordered list

Tags: thymeleaf

We have a `Set<String>` that we are printing to the page in `Thymeleaf`:

```
<h5>Unique Students names</h5>
<ol>
   <div th:each="uniqueName: ${course.uniqueStudentsNames}">
       <li th:text="${uniqueName}"></li>
   </div>
</ol>
```

Since it is a `Set<String>` there is no order of the items in the set.

We like to convert the non-ordered `Set<String>` to an ordred `List<String>` so we will be able to print it by ABC. Since it is a UI issue, we don't like the backend to change its data structure.

An option we thought about is to create such a list in the Model:

```
  model.addAttribute("course", course);
  model.addAttribute("orderedList", /* convert Set to ordred List */);
```

But this seems very strange that the Model needs to handle such a UI issue.

Is there a way to do it in Thymeleaf?

Answer (score 2):

Instantiate it as a TreeSet (you are probably using hashset?) and you have a set with the ordering behaviour you want. `Set<String>` (`Set<anything>` really) guarantees there won't be repeated items, but it does not imply anything about the order/unorder.

On the other side, thymeleaf, as a template engine, won't do such things as adding ordering behaviour to a collection that does not implement it. The most it will do is allow you to access methods of the collection; in the case of set: [set utility methods](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#sets).

If you no matter what want to use a non ordered set, you'd have to use something like javascript to manipulate the items on the client to order them.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Thymeleaf utility method to convert the object to a `List`:
`${#lists.toList(object)}`.

Then perform a utility operation to [sort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29168979/order-by-in-thymeleaf) as needed from there, optionally using your own `Comparator`.

The [current Thymeleaf source code](https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf/blob/3.0-master/src/main/java/org/thymeleaf/util/ListUtils.java) shows that the `toList()` method will check if the target object is an instance of `Iterable`.  In your case, `Set` implements the interface.

To reference the external link:

```
if (target instanceof Iterable<?>) {
    final List<Object> elements = new ArrayList<Object>(10);
    for (final Object element : (Iterable<?>)target) {
        elements.add(element);
    }
    return elements;
}
```